# Jquery code runs fine on localhost, but not on server

Tags: jquery, localhost

This is my first question on SO, and believe me, I've tried to find an answer to this question but to no avail.

I have a html form, which I am trying to validate using Jquery. The code below works fine on localhost (I'm using wamp) but when I've put this on the server, pressing the submit button causes the error message to appear, even when the email address is valid. The submit action still goes through, though I am using `e.preventDefault();` when the error occurs.

You can reproduce the issue at http://recharged.in/go-status.php

Here is the code:

```
<div id="gostatusdiv">
<h1>Status</h1>
<p>Check the status of your order by entering your email address below.<br/>If you are a registered user, your orders won't appear here.</p>
<form id="gostatusform" name="gostatusform" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<label for="gostatus"><b>Email Address:</b></label><span id="errorliemail" class="errormsgs" name="errorliemail">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;Invalid Email address&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </span><br/>
<input type="text" id="gostatus" name="gostatus" placeholder="Email you entered during your order" /><br/>
<input type="submit" id="gostatusbtn" value="Get my orders" name="submit" class="gostatusbtn buttons" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#gostatusform').on('submit', function(e){
        $('#errorliemail').slideUp();
        $("#gostatus").addClass("validfields");
        $("#gostatus").removeClass("invalidfields");
        var li_email = $("#gostatus").val();
        var mailtest = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
        //Validate Email ID
        if(!mailtest.test(li_email)) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#errorliemail').slideDown();
            $("#li_email").removeClass("validfields");
            $("#li_email").addClass("invalidfields");
        }
    });
</script>
</div>
```

I don't have the slightest clue about what might be causing this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I checked a valid email `aaa@bbb.gr` and it worked fine. Possibly a setting on the client? I am using firefox.

Comment: I have tried using Firefox and Chrome. The email address submission works fine, but it shows an "Invalid email address" error, which should appear only when the email entered is not valid (and in that case, submission should not work).

Comment: Ok, i see what you are saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, but looks like I stumbled into the solution myself. Changing the `slideDown()` and `slideUp()` to `show()` and `hide()` did the trick. Looks like the sliding animations aren't meant to run with span.

Still I am unsure why the same code ran without any problem on localhost, but gave problem when I uploaded it on the server.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you do when you hit submit is slideup the #errorliemail, no matter if the form is valid or not.

You should try something like that:

```
$('#gostatusform').on('submit', function(e){
    $("#gostatus").addClass("validfields");
    $("#gostatus").removeClass("invalidfields");
    var li_email = $("#gostatus").val();
    var mailtest = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
    //Validate Email ID
    if(!mailtest.test(li_email)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#errorliemail').slideDown();
        $("#li_email").removeClass("validfields");
        $("#li_email").addClass("invalidfields");
    }else{
        $('#errorliemail').slideUp();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that does look better. But still, doesn't solve the original problem.

Comment: What original problem? No submission if not valid?

Comment: When input is invalid, submission doesn't go through. But when the input is valid, the error message still shows up. I stopped the page just in time and found `style="display-inline"` in the span containing the error message (which I have set to `display:none` by default.)

Comment: I tried adding `!important` to the `display: none`, it prevents the error from appearing, but in both cases - even when the input is invalid email, thus defeating the purpose of the error message.